# Internal Error accessing Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

When I try to access Google Drive API with `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=title+%3D+%27data%27&alt=json&key=myapikey` I get a `500 Internal Error`.

Assuming that it's just the API that is horrible I guess the query is somewhat wrong.
Does anyone know how to fix it or even better how to look at the actual error?

Comment: Just to be clear - I checked that the App is connected in _drive_ and the `API_KEY` is correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Drive API - Error 500 - Simple API Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199088/google-drive-api-error-500-simple-api-access)