# Google Drive API - Error 500 - Simple API Access

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

For months I've been using the Google Drive API for simple access to fetch metadata about publicly shared document IDs. All of a sudden about a week ago (April 16) it stopped working.

I've tried repeatedly from different machines (PCs and Linux servers) with browsers and cURL and WGET, and I have even created new Google API accounts to try using different API keys, but it fails 100% of the time.

Example request URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0By7D4SJX3kYEaGpneE1VaUN6OG8?key=MYAPIKEY
```

Response body:

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": null
 }
}
```

Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
status: 500 Internal Server Error
version: HTTP/1.1
cache-control: private, max-age=0
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 66
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
date: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 17:39:49 GMT
expires: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 17:39:49 GMT
server: GSE
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

Is there a technical problem on the Google Drive servers that no one else is aware of? I've only seen one other report of this problem with zero feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now fixed, sorry for the issue.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick turnaround. I was a bit worried for a while. (Now gdurl.com is back online.) :-)